# How may I clear the cache of Mongoose web server?

Tags: windows, webserver, cache

I have recently started using Mongoose web server for Windows, after having run IIS for many years. I like the simplicity of Mongoose. However, I have run into a caching problem.

First, I had both an index.html and an index.php file in the same directory. As per default settings index.html has precedence over index.php, the html file was the one that showed.

I wanted the index.php file to show, so instead of changing the settings I deleted the index.html file. However, it still is the index.html file that shows.

I have tried restarting the server as well as using different browsers, but it will still show index.html.

How may I clean the cache of Mongoose web server?

Comment: Mongoose doesn't actually keep a cache of any sort. Browsers have their own cache, which can be cleaned up from the browser preferences dialog. Deleting index.html should be enough.. What is the URL, is it `http://localhost/` ? What happens when you stop mongoose and refresh index page?

Comment: When I tried today it worked. Strange, because if it was a browser cache issue, it would work when I switched browsers. No matter, now it works. Thanks for replying, valenok!